# Вывести адреса букв слова

Tags: c++, строки, указатели

Возник вопрос по поводу вывода адресов букв

```
string s;
getline(cin, s);
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    cout << &s[i] << "\n";
}
```

почему эта часть кода выводит не адреса букв, а:

[image]

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout << (void*)&s[i] << "\n";
```

Указатель `char*` выводится как строка.